# Send only one value from a constant block

Tags: constants, block, simulink

I thought this should be fairly simple, I really have no idea what went wrong, been trying for a week, gosh!! so ashamed of myself.

I define the following at Workspace: I=[5 5.1 5.2 5.2]; V=[95 80 85 20];

I expect an output like this: at t=0, arr=20, at t=1, arr=30, at t=0, arr=40,

When I run the simulation, what I got is: at t=0, arr=20, 0, 0, 0, at t=1, arr=0, 10, 0, 0, at t=2, arr=0, 0, 10, 0,

There are few problems with this result: 1. I expect only one arr value at a particular time, but it came out four arr values at a time

I wonder why the arr never adds up to 30 and 40 etc
My system is as follow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVv03.jpg

The codes are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMP5a.jpg

Comment: Probably you need to take the time as input to s-fucntion

Comment: do I understand you right: you want a single puls `v=5` at `t=0`, another single puls `v=5.1` at `t=1` and inbetween `v=0`? right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a "From workspace" block. That will help you send different values at each time step. You can specify your data for the block as a parameter. The block dialog shows you the format for this parameter. If you have DSP System toolbox, using "Signal From workspace" block will make this even simpler. All you need is to provide a vector of data and one value will be picked up at each time step. The doc for these two blocks are at

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/signalfromworkspace.html

Comment: Thanks Navan, I did try what you said, however I still get all four signals being sent to the output at t=0, four signals at t=1....etc. I want only one signal sent to the output at t=0 etc

Comment: The parameter format for the block might not be correct. Can you post which block you tried and how you set the parameter? The purpose of these two blocks is to send one signal at a time.

Comment: Thanks Navan, you are right, it is able to send one signal at a time. sorry my mistake. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi Navan. Could you please have a look on my edited question?

Comment: Your input to MATLAB Function block is not scalar. You are also creating an output arr which is 4x1 in your code. All the values from MATLAB Function block is sent out at the same time.

Comment: Hi Navan, thanks for your reply. I tried your approach, it did finally give me a single value at a particular time.  Now, I got this output: %// at t=0 arr = 20 %// at t=1 arr = 10 %// at t=2 arr = 10 May I know, why the arr never adds up to 30 and 40 etc? – I enable debugging and I am sure the count did increase from 1 to 2, 3 and so on. However, the integ_signal(count,1) contains very weird value such as 0.3412 etc. I have no idea what went wrong in this simple code. only one of its value is modified but it is not the right value

Comment: Hi Navan, please please have a look, I just need some idea so i can troubleshoot, the model and code are here> http://imgur.com/thdjrRb, http://imgur.com/g9OM59Y

Comment: integ_signal is initialized to zeros at each time step. If you want old values of integ_signal to persist use "persistent integ_signal" and initialize it using "if isempty(integ_signal)" construct.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to input your values from the workspace and you want to stay in Simulink:
Use the Signal Builder source block. When you double-click on it you can create signals graphically.

For example:[image: Signal Builder Editor]